# Is there a short cut to test all variables besides one?

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I'm trying to run a regression model for all two-way interactions and have about ~70 variables for each observation.

I have a certain variable, say z, that I want to model the main effects for but exclude from all two way interactions.

So right now I have something like this:

```
lm(y ~ .^2, data = d)
```

I'd like an easy way to do this:

```
lm(y ~ . + (not z)^2, data = d)
```

I know it's a lot of variables, I'm an academic researcher and just need to see what's significant when I run the model with everything in it. For my purposes, z makes sense as a main effect but not as an interaction from an intuitive perspective.

Thank you!

Comment: do you mean 70 observations per variable? I hope so ... (if you have enough variables you will still be in trouble since the number of parameters grows as the square of the number of variables ...)

Answer (score 3):

As Ritchie Sacramento and I discussed in the comments, this should work:

```r
lm(mpg ~ (. - carb)^2 + carb, data=mtcars)
```

The `. - carb` would create the formula with all but the carb variable, which is then added afterwards.

For your data, it would be something like this:

```
lm(y ~ (.-z)^2 + z, data = d)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can put this together with some string manipulations and `reformulate`.

Sample data (we're not even going to try to fit a model, just figure out how to construct the formula, so this should be OK).

```r
dd <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3, f=1:3)
```

Let's suppose `a` is the response and `f` is the focal variable that you want to include only as a main effect.

```r
v1 <- paste(setdiff(names(dd), c("a","f")), collapse = "+")
v2 <- sprintf("(%s)^2", v1)
form <- reformulate(c(v2, "f"), response = "a")
## a ~ (b + c + d + e)^2 + f
colnames(model.matrix(form, data = dd))
```

results:

```r
 [1] "(Intercept)" "b"           "c"           "d"           "e"          
 [6] "f"           "b:c"         "b:d"         "b:e"         "c:d"        
[11] "c:e"         "d:e"
```

Confirming that @FlapJack's answer also works:

```r
 colnames(model.matrix(a ~ (. - f)^2 + f, data = dd))
 [1] "(Intercept)" "b"           "c"           "d"           "e"          
 [6] "f"           "b:c"         "b:d"         "b:e"         "c:d"        
[11] "c:e"         "d:e"
```

(On the other hand, you could use my framework to do more complicated things like include/exclude variables on the basis of regular expressions ...)